# Where can New Mexico early voting statistics be obtained?

Tags: united-states, voting, statistics, data-sources, new-mexico

I am following the special election in New Mexico's 1st district.

I found this from an article [here](https://www.krqe.com/news/politics-government/elections/few-cast-votes-for-congressional-district-1-special-election/):

> According to the Secretary of State’s Office, more than 1,000
> Democrats have voted, about 400 Republicans, and around 150 from other
> parties or no party.

How can I obtain updated information on who voted in this special and by party affiliation if possible?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this data doesn't appear to be freely available. It can be purchased from the New Mexico Secretary of State's Office [here](https://www.sos.state.nm.us/voting-and-elections/data-and-maps/voter-data-information/), in accordance with Section 1.10.35.10 of the New Mexico Administrative Code:

> **1.10.35.10 VOTER RECORDS REQUESTS:**
>
> A. All requesters of voter file data or public service requests shall
> complete the affidavit of authorization prescribed by the secretary of
> state.
>
> B. The secretary of state shall develop a uniform fee schedule for
> data recording media, voter data, voter lists, special voter lists,
> precinct lists, printed labels, and **early and absentee daily voting
> reports**. County clerks may require a deposit for any data requested.
>  <sub>[Source - LII](https://www.law.cornell.edu/regulations/new-mexico/NMAC-1-10-35-10)</sub>

The only other journalistic source that seems to be publishing this information is the [Albequerque Journal (May 6th)](https://www.abqjournal.com/2388059/cd1-race-offers-first-chance-to-register-vote-through-election-day.html). The author of that article has released updated data from May 10th [on his Twitter account](https://twitter.com/DanBoydNM/status/1391802962599571456).